# Is an isentropic process always adiabatic?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, adiabatic, carnot-cycle

I am making an exercise about a pulsating jet engine. There is a part in the cycle of this engine that is an isentropic expansion and i'm wondering if I can use $PV^{g} = cte $ in this process

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Examples of processes that are reversible isentropic but not adiabatic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562158/)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes thank you!